# numberOfItemsInSection not sent to datasource

Tags: macos, uicollectionview, appkit, nscollectionview

I built a NSCollectionView programmatically in a popover as a part of menubar App for OSX. But when clicking the status item, the numberOfItemsInSection was always sent to a NSButton. I tried to investigate but got nothing. The code snippet is like:

```
 class MyViewController: NSViewController, 
                         NSCollectionViewDataSource,
                         NSCollectionViewDelegate,
                        NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

     override func loadView() {

        ...

        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = NSCollectionViewFlowLayout()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self

        ...
    }

}

// MARK: NSCollectionViewDataSource

    func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView,
        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10;
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
}
```

Error message:

2016-04-05 06:13:44.561 [24387:1271747] -[NSButton collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000001434f0

2016-04-05 06:13:44.561 [24387:1271747] -[NSButton collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000001434f0

2016-04-05 06:13:44.564 [24387:1271747] (

0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff96f764f2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8b5cf73c objc_exception_throw + 48

2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff96fe01ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205

3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff96ee6571 ***forwarding*** + 1009

4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff96ee60f8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120

5   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff89c05e5b -[NSCollectionViewData _updateItemCounts] + 355

6   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff89c06123 -[NSCollectionViewData _prepareToLoadData] + 73

7   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff89c067d5 -[NSCollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:] + 51

8   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff89c43adb -[_NSCollectionViewCore _layoutItems] + 135

9   AppKit                              0x00007fff9aca2393 -[NSCollectionView viewWillDraw] + 108

10  AppKit                              0x00007fff9a57ba94 -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 1163

11  AppKit                              0x00007fff9a57ba94 -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 1163

12  AppKit                              0x00007fff9a57b24a -[NSView _sendViewWillDrawInRect:clipRootView:] + 1705

13  AppKit                              0x00007fff9a579247 -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1260

14  AppKit                              0x00007fff9a578d40 -[NSWindow displayIfNeeded] + 232

15  AppKit                              0x00007fff9abfd4bb ___NSWindowGetDisplayCycleObserver_block_invoke6365 + 476

16  AppKit                              0x00007fff9a5786da __37+[NSDisplayCycle currentDisplayCycle]_block_invoke + 941

17  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff88f70f71 _ZN2CA11Transaction19run_commit_handlersE18CATransactionPhase + 85

18  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff88f7042c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 160

19  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff88f700ec _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 508

20  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff88f7b977 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 71

21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff96f0b067 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23

22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff96f0afd7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391

23  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff96ee9ef8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 328

24  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff9c6f1935 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235

25  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff9c6f1677 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 184

26  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff9c6f15af _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71

27  AppKit                              0x00007fff9a420efa _DPSNextEvent + 1067

28  AppKit                              0x00007fff9a42032a -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454

29  AppKit                              0x00007fff9a414e84 -[NSApplication run] + 682

30  AppKit                              0x00007fff9a3de46c NSApplicationMain + 1176

31                                0x0000000100063734 main + 84

32  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff9b3995ad start + 1

33  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)